# How can I most efficiently subdivide a plane in a brick/tile-like pattern in order to generate geometric complexity for displacement mapping?

Tags: texturing, edges, geometry, subdivision-surface, displacement

I have a (repeating) texture of a tiled sidewalk on a plane:

[image: Tile texture on a plane]

I wish to use a displacement map on this plane for the deeper grooves between the tiles (I use a normal map for the "stoney" roughness). Now in order to keep my vertex count at a minimum, I wish to only add geometric complexity at those grooves, where it is needed. Considering only the horizontal grooves, it should like something like this:

[image: Added edges only at the horizontal grooves]

What is the most efficient (in terms of both time and vertex count) way to add edges on the plane only at all grooves? The mirror modifier is not really an option, since the texture is not perfectly symmetrical. I am using Cycles.

Comment: If you really want those grooves as real geometry model a plane for one tile and add Array modifier, adjust as needed. Then do the same for the rest of tiles. Although I wouldn't tell this is wise way to model at all, texture for the bump map will work as well and you likely won't ever see grooves themselves from that distance to tell the difference

Comment: The end result will have the camera move closer to the plane, at a distance where the difference between normal mapping and displacement mapping is pretty noticeable (could be because I use a rather low res texture and a rather crappy normal map which I generated from it). But your solution sounds pretty good, but that still seems like a lot of work to still connect all those array modified planes (I need at least four edges between each pair of tiles). I cannot fathom there is no way to just duplicate a selection of edges and slide those across the plane.

Comment: The most efficient way is to not use displacement at all which sounds like a blunt brute force solution here. You have a nicely repeating simple tiled pattern, model it and then use an array, or better yet instance it for maximum optimization.

Comment: If camera is going to be close then it might be indeed better to model, note though that in this case you likely won't get away a lot of work with only modeled cubes as tiles, I would say they should be evenly subdivided, sculpted, baked to lowpoly and only then you can use cube per tile. So in general if polycount is important don't use one model for details and render.

Comment: Thank you for your input! I will attempt to model the tiles. Just for the sake of completeness: there is no way to just duplicate a selection of edges and slide those across the plane?

Comment: Not in "modeling inside one mesh" way. If you *duplicate* edge loops they will become new mesh, not connected in any way to the original one. What you can try is in Object mode create several curve objects, adjust them to grooves location, then join and use Knife Project to cut over big plane covering all the tiles area. Though I think Array modifier way is far more configurable.